# How can the color blind distinguish instinct vs mystic gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am completely color blind (meaning I cannot recognize any color) and having difficulty telling apart the mystic gym vs the instinct gym.

I can clearly identify a valor gym, when I open the gym, they use dark colored fonts in the player name and pokemon info. I have no problem with valor.

But with mystic and instinct, they are hard to tell apart. They use a light colored player name over a less light level number on the upper right hand of the open gym screen.

Just wondering if anyone has any suggestions. I am not blind. My color blindness allows me to tell apart light things from dark things, but I cannot say when something is blue or yellow.

It used to be i could tell before battling if I am facing enemy or ally because I would either see 6 or 1 attackers. But now this method does not work.

Comment: I wish I could help you man sorry. Did you have a look at different techniques for telling apart blue and yellow? Maybe there is a technique you're not aware of?

Comment: What team are you? If you are mystic or instinct, you can probably tell the difference by the options they give you at the gym. For example, if you are mystic, and click on a gym you are not sure of... if the gym is mystic, it should give you the 'train' button. If it is instinct, it should give you the 'attack' button option.

Comment: @king14nyr That should probably be an answer, and not a comment. Can you attach screenshots to illustrate the difference between the training icon (boxing glove) and the battle icon?

Comment: @Kent wanted to check on which team he was, as that solution wouldn't have been viable if he was Valor  (then both instinct and mystic would give the attack icon, and still be indistinguishable). Also, working on a phone isn't the easiest for making a nice answer with good resources, links, etc. :)

Comment: The issue doesn't matter if I was Valor as valor is easy to distinguish. In hindsight, perhaps I should have chosen that team. The issue arises because I am one of mystic and instinct. The main thing for me was to distinguish between foe or ally. However, the situation may arise in the future that i might play valor and find myself in the need to distinguish a gym as either mystic or instinct--that possibility cannot be ruled entirely but its not a current issue. it would be nice if there was a way to distinguish in that circumstance.

Comment: Perhaps you might [submit feedback](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us) to Niantic about this.

Answer (score 7):

The response from king14nyr and Kent has led me to a solution to the problem. The attack/train icon buttons are different and leads to a simple way to discriminate. Boxing glove is for training and the other icon with the zig zag lines or 6 pointed star is for attack.

[This page](http://www.appunwrapper.com/2016/07/11/pokemon-go-walkthrough-guide-gyms-explained/) has a close up of both icons in the open gym screen.